# Losing features when merging vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge

Trying the v.clean command and checked the layer with Topology checker and it turned out every single geometry was invalid.

What to do now?

[image]

---

Original question:

I have two shapefiles with 3D building blocks that I want to merge (Both MultiPolygonZ-type, the same columns in attribute table with the same projection). The blocks represent houses in two different area of the city (no overlaps).

*Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge vector layers* works great except that some features in the merged file looses it's solidness, see example below:

Houses from one of the shapes before merge (all houses are solid):

[image]

The same canvas from the merged file (some features loose their solidness):
[image]

Has anyone experienced the same problem and been able to workaround it?

Links below to two of the shape-files I'm trying to merge if anyone want to try and re-create the problem:

Dataset A: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFHJFrNX33hbGFHS2ZCeUVJNWc

Dataset B: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFHJFrNX33hZGFoT2xiVXZSbGs

Comment: Which QGIS version?

Comment: 2.18.0 Las Palmas

Comment: The same problem occurs when saving one of the vector layers to re-project it to a different projection. Some of the solid blocks disappears as soon as qgis does anything with it.

Comment: After the merge the type changed from MultipolygonZ to PolygonZ. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Those links are only the .shp files - they are missing all the extra files which need to be zipped with the .shp file to make them usable.

Comment: My bad! I've updated the original post with links to compressed datasets including all files. Although, I must admit - I've never understood how to make use of the other stuff. /Rookie

Comment: @johlund - Can you describe what you mean by the layer losing features? I can't see where the problem is =)

Comment: See the pictures in the original post. The first one have solid blocks with z-values and after merge - as you can see in picture two - some houses appears to have lost their solidness (or z-value) as they also project flat with Qgis2threejs. Better?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue dossolving polygons, the problem was that there were Geometry Errors. Bare in mind my process was a Standalone application, however the concept should help. Before performing the merge I ran

```
validate= processing.runalg("grass7:v.clean",CleanedOutput,0,0.1,extents,-1,0.0001,InFeature,errorsOutput)
```

This tool is simply a GRASS tool called v.clean, you can search for it from your processing toolbox. This tool cleans the geometry of the input vector layer, read about this more [HERE](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/v.clean.html)

[image: The different types of v.clean]

If you don't trust the v.clean to solv the problems, You can also use the [Check Geometry Validity](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html) from fTools plugin, to inspect the file manually, this tool will highlight all geometry errors, enter edit mode to solve the errors by deleting duplicate Nodes, Polygon overlaps etc.

Once the Geometry errors are dealt with the files should merge, dissolve, intersect, without losing features.

Another method I used was the GDAL tools ogr2ogr

```
To create a file to merge into use the following command. This will take a shapefile and copy it to a file called merge.shp (this filename is up to you).

ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ merge.shp filename1.shp
Then merge the following files by using:

ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ -update -append merge.shp filename2.shp -nln merge
ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ -update -append merge.shp filename3.shp -nln merge
```

[read more here](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/ogr2ogr-merge-shapefiles)

*Note you need the OSGeo4W shell provided with the For [Advanced Users Download](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) * This should help defeat the geometry errors
Hopefully this solves your issue, I remember how frustrating it was with me.