# Voronoi Polygon Algorithm seems to exclude a Point from processing

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I am using the QGIS (2.8.1) Voronoi Polygons Algorithm on a point shapefile. 
See image below, the red triangles are the points I am using. 
The resulting polygons miss a part (around HP87).

Any ideas why?

[image: Resulting voronoi polygons]

Here is some example data (EPSG:2154) that reproduces the error (excluding point A):

```
X,Y,NAME
816682.58,6391443.637,A
820180.458,6391708.558,B
821325.8429,6394449.982,C
822550.1316,6397547.124,D
```

Comment: I see this weird phenomena in QGIS 2.18.16, with QGIS geoalgorithm and v.voronoi. (Potentially related to an unanswered [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220591/voronoi-thiessen-polygons-doesnt-create-a-part-for-1-of-4-input-points)  ). They seem to ignore outmost point. SAGA `Thiessen polygons` is unaffected...

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto A sample data was added. Will you give it a go? (I am  testing it with various buffer region. It behaves strange when the buffer exceeds approx. 9 ~10.)

Comment: There were several bugs in the QGIS Voronoi code. Should be fixed in QGIS 3.2.2. Could you try it?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested in QGIS with 2 different tools. The grass `v.voronoi` and the internal `voronoi`.

From QGIS the `v.voronoi` doesn't work properly (it lacks polygons in my case):
[image]

Howerver the `voronoi` tool seems to work properly:
[image]

Here is my config:
[image]